# exporting query from SQL SERVER 2000 to csv file

Tags: sql-server

This is the first time I want to create a .crv file myself. I wish to create if using a query that I create from database in SQL Server. Can anyone tell me how to do so? 1 more thing, if I change any data in database, can data from .crv file auto update?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bcp` utility to export data from DB to CSV file. More details on this can be found [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3391761/Utilize-BCP-with-SQL-Server-2000.htm)

However, the file won't be auto-updated if data changes. You will need to regenerate the file.